# Square up Flow History Clear

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am learning android MVP pattern implementation with Square up Motor & Flow concept. I dont know how to clear my Flow history after user login is succeed. Any one can suggest how to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
Flow.get(context).setHistory(
    History.emptyBuilder().push(new AfterLoginState()).build(), 
    Direction.FORWARD
);
```

Comment: Thanks Epic. Instead of empty Builder , I tried History.single()  which is looks like below one,   Flow.get(context).setHistory(History.single(new IntroScreen()), Flow.Direction.FORWARD);  This method is also doing the same,

Comment: Yep, does the exact same thing, I just figured this one is slightly more generic :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about this [Dagger injection singleton principal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997218/dagger-2-create-singleton-instance)?