# Dagger 2 create singleton instance

Tags: android, dagger-2

Consider the scenario that I am calling Webservice at Presenter A and holding the response data at the same Presenter. I want to utilize the same response data at Presenter E.  But I cant pass the response object to each presenter B, C, D. So, I tried to store my response object at separate Holder class with getter & setter.  I initialized Holder class using Dagger Inject constructor annotation and tried to consume it at Presenter E . But I got Empty response instead of my datas . Can any one suggest me to handle this scenario in best way . Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add the scope `@Singleton` to your `@Provides` annotated method for the holder.

Comment: Even I tried with SingleTon pattern. It doesn't work for me. I will upload my project into GIT. I don't know what I missed.

Comment: I'll try to look into it when I get there

Comment: EpicPandaForce : I tried to create a sample project again with the same libraries to share with you. But while Running the application I got a null pointer exception on "'mortar.MortarScope mortar.MortarScope.findChild(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference" . Could you able to recognize what I have missed it.

Comment: I have added my source code at Git hub. Link is provided below. In that I consume a webservice at Screen A, and I tried to utilize it at Screen B. I can print the response at Screen A but it becomes null at Screen B. Please have a look on it and let me know what I missed it , github.com/Jeyahariprakash/DaggerPoc –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **lot** of fundamental problems with how you're using Dagger2, but my time is limited, so I'll answer for the time being regarding Mortar - all I can say is that on some devices, `getSystemService()` is called sooner in `Application` than `onCreate()`, which means you should initialize your root mortar scope like this:

```
@Override
public Object getSystemService(String name) {
    if(rootScope == null) {
        rootScope = MortarScope.buildRootScope()
                .withService(InjectorService.TAG, new InjectorService(this))
                .build("Root");
    }
    if(rootScope.hasService(name)) { // if the additional "Context" service is within Mortar
        return rootScope.getService(name);
    }
    return super.getSystemService(name); // otherwise return application level context system service
}
```

Personally, I had this in my `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    realmHolder = new RealmHolder();
    ApplicationHolder.INSTANCE.setApplication(this);
    appConfig = new AppConfig(this);
    InjectorService.obtain().inject(this); // <--- this one obtains component
    initializeRealm();
}
```

And in InjectorService:

```
public static ApplicationComponent obtain() {
    return ((InjectorService) MortarScope.getScope(ApplicationHolder.INSTANCE.getApplication())
            .getService(TAG)).getComponent();
}
```

As such, in the worst case scenario, `getSystemService()` initialized my RootScope either at start-up, or when the singleton dagger component was created.

This solution is currently not multi-process friendly (so Firebase Crash Reporting would kill it by calling `onCreate()` in `CustomApplication` twice)

EDIT: Injector Service code

```
public class InjectorService {
    public static final String TAG = "InjectorService";

    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent; //dagger2 app level component

    InjectorService(CustomApplication customApplication) {
        AppContextModule appContextModule = new AppContextModule(customApplication);
        RealmModule realmModule = new RealmModule();
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .appContextModule(appContextModule)
                .realmModule(realmModule)
                .build();
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getInjector() { //return the app component to inject `this` with it
        return applicationComponent;
    }

    public static InjectorService get(Context context) {
        //this is needed otherwise the compiler is whining. -_-
        //noinspection ResourceType
        return (InjectorService) context.getSystemService(TAG);
    }

    public static ApplicationComponent obtain() {
        return ((InjectorService) MortarScope.getScope(ApplicationHolder.INSTANCE.getApplication())
                .getService(TAG)).getInjector();
    }
}
```

---

As for your initial question, it's because you added `@Inject` annotation to your constructor, but did not include `@Singleton` on the class itself

```
@Singleton
public class Blah {
    @Inject
    public Blah() {
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I got home from vacation, so initial error is

> Error:(40, 5) error: com.hari.daggerpoc.application.App.Component scoped with 
>   @com.hari.daggerpoc.frameworks.dagger.DaggerScope may not reference
>   bindings with different scopes:
>   @Singleton class com.hari.daggerpoc.cache.ResponseCache

It refers to this class in `App`:

```
@dagger.Component(modules = {Module.class})
@DaggerScope(Component.class)
public interface Component extends AppDependencies {

    void inject(App app);
}
```

Which inherits from this class:

```
@Module(includes = {Utils.class, ResponseCache.class})
public interface AppDependencies {

    Utils utils();

    ResponseCache responseCache();

}
```

...which is totally NOT a module,  so that annotation is unnecessary, but hey.

Anyways, the issue *now* is that while the dependency is scoped, it is from a different scope (I didn't know the singleton scope isn't used), so if you change

```
@Singleton
public class ResponseCache {
    @Inject
    public ResponseCache(){    
    }
```

to

```
@DaggerScope(App.Component.class)
public class ResponseCache {

    @Inject
    public ResponseCache(){

    }
```

Then if in `ScreenA` you change

```
    public Callback<WeatherResponse> configServiceCallback = new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
            Log.d("ScreenA","Response data -->"+response.body().toString());
            Flow.get(context).setHistory(History.single(new ScreenB()), Flow.Direction.FORWARD);
            responseCache.setWeatherResponse(response.body());
        }
```

to

```
    public Callback<WeatherResponse> configServiceCallback = new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
            Log.d("ScreenA","Response data -->"+response.body().toString());
            responseCache.setWeatherResponse(response.body());
            Flow.get(context).setHistory(History.single(new ScreenB()), Flow.Direction.FORWARD);
        }
```

Then it says

```
08-28 18:12:48.369 31253-31253/com.hari.daggerpoc D/ScreenA: Response data -->WeatherResponse{endpoint=Endpoint{url='http://www.waynedgrant.com/weather/api/weather.json', version=1.7, githubProject='null', copyright='Copyright © 2016 Wayne D Grant (www.waynedgrant.com)'}}
08-28 18:12:48.369 31253-31253/com.hari.daggerpoc D/ScreenB: Response cache -->WeatherResponse{endpoint=Endpoint{url='http://www.waynedgrant.com/weather/api/weather.json', version=1.7, githubProject='null', copyright='Copyright © 2016 Wayne D Grant (www.waynedgrant.com)'}}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, You are returning the app component at obtain() method, which I was injected directly . But I am confused where you are creating component over here?? Rest is pretty much same as my code since you are also injecting component at onCreate method only..          And I tried to add  Singleton annotation at AppDependencies.class / Utils.class .. But while compiling it throws me error that  "com.hari.daggerpoc.application.App.Component scoped with com.hari.daggerpoc.frameworks.dagger.DaggerScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
Singleton Utils"

Comment: added `InjectorService` code. The `new InjectorService(this)` is called in `withService()`.

Comment: So you should put `@Singleton` on **ResponseCache** class

Comment: As I told earlier , I am getting below error If I am using Single ton "com.hari.daggerpoc.ui.presenter.ScreenA.Component scoped with '@'com.hari.daggerpoc.frameworks.dagger.DaggerScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
'@'Singleton class com.hari.daggerpoc.cache.ResponseCache"

Comment: That's because you need to add `ResponseCache responseCache();` to `AppDependencies`  interface

Comment: I have done that also Epic! Still I dont know what happening behind Dagger scope. You can check out my git code.. I have did recent commit of single ton Response cache.. I am getting the same error...

Comment: Hmm that is odd :( That should have solved **that** issue. Sad news is that I'll be leaving for vacation in 10 minutes, and I'll only be back on Sunday.

Comment: well I returned from the vacation

Comment: I couldn't fix that issue. By any chance did you able to find out the issue?

Comment: Hey! You found out ..  I stuck up with this issue past one week. Thank you so much..So, the issue is with Dagger custom Scope.  If I am not wrong this App component scope will be available through out the application . Am i rite??

Comment: Yep, if you keep it throughout the app, then it will be available throughout the app :) Changing your scope to `@DaggerScope(App.Component.class)` fixed it :thumbsup:

Comment: I have one more interesting scenario  " http://stackoverflow.com/q/39247536/5276035?stw=2".. Do you have any idea how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine this solution to your problem.

The point is, you need to remove from your presenter the `ApiRequest` and use a `interactor`, the both presenter receives this Interactor injected in his constructor, in this case they will share the same interactor instance (if he was a singleton). The interactor is responsible for doing the cache, if you are using `OkHttpClient` you can make the cache without using a `holder class`(up to you), in this solution you will not perform 2 api calls for the same data.

Something like this:

```
public class PresenterA (){
    private UserInteractor userInteractor;
    private ViewA view;

    public PresenterA(UserInteractor interactor, ViewA view){
        this.interactor = interactor;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void getUser(){
        interactor.findFirst(new MyCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(User user){
                view.loadUserName(user.getName());
            }
        });
    }
}

public class PresenterB (){
    private UserInteractor userInteractor;
    private ViewB view;

    public PresenterA(UserInteractor interactor, ViewB view){
        this.interactor = interactor;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void getUser(){
        interactor.findFirst(new MyCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(User user){
                view.loadAddress(user.getAddress().getLine1());
            }
        });
    }
}

public class UserInteractor (){
    private MyHolderData holder;
    private MyApi api;

    public UserInteractor(MyHolderData holder, MyApi api){
        this.holder = holder;
        this.api = api;
    }

    public User getUser(){
        if(holder.hasCache()){
            return holder.getUser();
        }
        api.requestUser(new MyApiCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(User user){
                return user;
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I am using OkHttpClient with Retrofit library. But I don't want to cache the response for my web service.  Assume, When ever I am opening my application I need to call the weather webservice at PresenterA  which is present at Sceen 1 and I want to display the weather details at PresenterD which is present at Screen 4 . So, created a single ton class to store response object and tried to utilize it on other screens. But its not working fine

Comment: Just create a holder with your WebService response and share with your presenters (like the example), if you could post your code with problem I could help.

Comment: To share my code , I try to create the sample project.  This time I got null pointer exception on "'mortar.MortarScope mortar.MortarScope.findChild(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference" . I am trying to fix this now. Do you have any idea abt this?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you with mortar, this question is about dagger-2, not mortar, I suggest you write a new question about this null pointer in mortar TAG.

Comment: I have added my source code at Git hub. Link is provided below. In that I consume a webservice at Screen A, and I tried to utilize it at Screen B.  I can print the response at Screen A but it becomes null at Screen B. Please have a look on it and let me know what I missed it , https://github.com/Jeyahariprakash/DaggerPoc